# Gitlab pages & nanoc -> Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, nanoc

I'm trying out gitlab pages with a static website which is compiled via nanoc. When I commit my code to my gitlab repo the runner fails to compiling it. I get following error message:

Runner output:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.6.0 (01b3ea1)
Using Docker executor with image ruby:2.3 ...
Pulling docker image ruby:2.3 ...
Running on runner-......
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/builds/username/testproject'...
Checking out a486d496 as master...
$ bundle install -j4
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Installing colored 1.2
Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Installing tilt 2.0.5
Installing kramdown 1.12.0
Installing rack 2.0.1
Using bundler 1.13.1
Installing ref 2.0.0
Installing cri 2.7.0
Installing hamster 3.0.0
Installing haml 4.0.7
Installing adsf 1.2.1
Installing nanoc 4.3.3
Bundle complete! 4 Gemfile dependencies, 12 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into /usr/local/bundle.
Post-install message from haml:

HEADS UP! Haml 4.0 has many improvements, but also has changes that may break
your application:

* Support for Ruby 1.8.6 dropped
* Support for Rails 2 dropped
* Sass filter now always outputs <style> tags
* Data attributes are now hyphenated, not underscored
* html2haml utility moved to the html2haml gem
* Textile and Maruku filters moved to the haml-contrib gem

For more info see:

http://rubydoc.info/github/haml/haml/file/CHANGELOG.md

$ nanoc
Loading site… 
Captain! We’ve been hit!

Message:

Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory

Compilation stack:

(empty)

Stack trace:

  0. /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/find.rb:43:in `block in find'
  1. /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/find.rb:43:in `collect!'
  2. /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/find.rb:43:in `find'
  3. /usr/local/bundle/gems/nanoc-4.3.3/lib/nanoc/extra/pruner.rb:37:in `run'
  4. /usr/local/bundle/gems/nanoc-4.3.3/lib/nanoc/base/compilation/compiler.rb:186:in `prune'
  5. /usr/local/bundle/gems/nanoc-4.3.3/lib/nanoc/base/compilation/compiler.rb:77:in `run_all'
  6. /usr/local/bundle/gems/nanoc-4.3.3/lib/nanoc/base/entities/site.rb:30:in `compile'
  7. /usr/local/bundle/gems/nanoc-4.3.3/lib/nanoc/cli/commands/compile.rb:406:in `block in run'
  8. /usr/local/bundle/gems/nanoc-4.3.3/lib/nanoc/cli/commands/compile.rb:442:in `run_listeners_while'
  9. /usr/local/bundle/gems/nanoc-4.3.3/lib/nanoc/cli/commands/compile.rb:405:in `run'
  ... 17 more lines omitted. See full crash log for details.

If you believe this is a bug in Nanoc, please do report it at
-> https://github.com/nanoc/nanoc/issues/new <-

A detailed crash log has been written to ./crash.log.
done
Compiling site…
ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: ruby:2.3

pages:
  script:
  - bundle install -j4
  - nanoc
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```

Answer (score 1):

The **public** directory was missing within my repo. As soon as I pushed this directory into the remote, the runner could compile and deploy my page.